# aarch64 MMU translation table

Tags: arm64, mmu, page-tables

I've been experimenting with MMU on RPi3B+ with no success at all. I tried following official ARM examples, and I generate tables like this:

Level 2 table is at 1016000 PA:

```
0000000001016000: 0000000000000405 0000000000200405 0000000000400405 0000000000600405
0000000001016020: 0000000000800405 0000000000A00405 0000000000C00405 0000000000E00405
0000000001016040: 0000000001000405 0000000001200405 0000000001400405 0000000001600405
...
0000000001016FC0: 006000003F000601 006000003F200601 006000003F400601 006000003F600601
0000000001016FE0: 006000003F800601 006000003FA00601 006000003FC00601 006000003FE00601
```

Level 1 table is at 1014000:

```
0000000001014000: 0000000001016003 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0000000001014020: 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
...
0000000001014FE0: 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
```

The only entry in Level 1 table is the one that points to a Level 2 table.

```
MAIR: 0x000000000044FF00
TCR: 0x0000000000803520
```

Anyway, when I enable MMU, I lose any other information, as UART does not work anymore. This should be 1:1 mapping in EL1. I tried experimenting with both 32bits and 39bits VA space in TCR. Also with enabling ttbr1, nothing works at all. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: This works perfectly in qemu-system-aarch64 -M raspi3, but not on device when using U-Boot. Also it does not work if loaded directly in RPi (at 0x80000). Any explanation as to why is welcome.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you set `T1SZ` to `0`, so the `TTBR1` range would in theory span the whole address space and overlap with the `TTBR0` range. I see you disable `TTBR1` translation, but base register selection should happen before that is even considered. Maybe try setting `T1SZ` to `0b100000`?

Comment: The same doesn't work for 0x00000000B5A03520, for example. Tried numerous other values. Tried also to shift address for Level 1 entry for 12, and for 21 in Level 2 entries (according to some other tutorials (!) ) Sorry for the rant, but to be honest, examples and tutorials both from ARM and from other users are just plain horrible! Either they are overly complex or unreadable or they do not work at all! Or they are overly generic. I mean, I may be really really stupid, but entering simple values into registers shouldn't be rocket science. Seems they are going the x86 path.

Comment: I mean, it could always be the TLB or caches messing you up as well... without seeing your code, there's no way to tell.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I also tried not enabling the D-cache and I-cache at all when enabling MMU, maybe I should play around with that some more. But, if you can only provide me with information that the page table entries are consistent with how I configured MAIR and TCR, that would be really helpful, so I can concentrate on troubleshooting other stuff. Edit: The reason I haven't shared my code is because it has grown a bit too much already. But if you know what to look for, I can provide you with snippets, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem was somewhere in my code for enabling / disabling MMU. Because I wanted to keep the same logic in early start and when enabling MMU, I wrote this macro:

```
.macro set_mmu_el el enabled
    mov   x0, xzr

    ldr     x2, =\enabled
    lsl     x1, x2, #12
    orr     x0, x0, x1
    lsl     x1, x2, #2
    orr     x0, x0, x1
    orr     x0, x0, x2

    msr     sctlr_el\el, x0
.endm
```

Then, this was called in:

```
.globl mmu_enable_el1
mmu_enable_el1:
    sub     sp, sp, #0x16
    str     x30, [sp]

    dsb ish
    isb

    set_mmu_el 1 _MMU_ENABLED
    isb

    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop

    ldr     x30, [sp]
    add     sp, sp, #0x16

    ret
```

And again, this was called in:

```
void mmu_init() {
    // ...
    mmu_enable_el1();
}
```

I replaced this with only:

```
asm volatile("dsb ish; isb; msr sctlr_el1, %0; isb; nop; nop; nop; nop"::"r"(0x000005 | (1 << 12)));
```

Now it works perfectly, with both D-cache and I-cache enabled. I am not sure what went wrong with the code above, but anyway, a lesson has been learned. At least my page table format was correct.